# Flyway Java based migration on multiple shards

Tags: java, spring-boot, database-migration, flyway, schema-migration

Followed [this](https://javadeveloperzone.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-flyway-java-based-migration-example/) blog for creating simple java based migrations in flyway with one datasource connection. But in application, we will be having multiple shards and have feasibility to choose migration to run on one particular shard or all shards. But for multiple shards , we will be having different set of values for the below properties

```
flyway.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/demo_database_1
flyway.user=root
flyway.password=
```

Our application migration steps, ( these are manual steps running inside docker container with flyway base image. These steps will run sequentially inside docker )

DEMO_0 shard migration:

```
flyway -url='jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo_0?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true' -user=root -password=root -locations=filesystem:./sql/global/migrations info
flyway -url='jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo_0?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true' -user=root -password=root -validateOnMigrate="false" -locations=filesystem:./sql/global/migrations migrate
```

DEMO_1 shard migration:

```
flyway -url='jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo_1?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true' -user=root -password=root -locations=filesystem:./sql/data/migrations info
flyway -url='jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo_1?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true' -user=root -password=root -validateOnMigrate="false" -locations=filesystem:./sql/data/migrations migrate
```

Is there a way in flyway to give multiple flyway urls to migrate?
And also is SQL based migration is better or java based migration?